# Как удалить сообщение(и добавить другие флаги) на почте используя imap?

Tags: c#, email, imap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я пытаюсь удалить сообщение с почты используя следующий синтаксис,но это не работает,хотя ответ появляется "Ok.Successes",как можно решить данную проблему?

```
var req = "$ UID STORE " + email.Uid + @" +flags (\Deleted)" + "\r\n";
 Console.WriteLine(ReceiveResponse("$ SELECT INBOX\r\n").Replace("\0",""));
 Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");        
 Console.WriteLine(ReceiveResponse(req).Replace("\0", ""));
 Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
 Console.WriteLine(ReceiveResponse("$ EXPUNGE" + "\r\n"));

private string ReceiveResponse(string command)
            {
                _sb = new StringBuilder();
                try
                {
                    if (command != "")
                    {
                        if (_tcpClient.Connected)
                        {
                            _dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                            _ssl.Write(_dummy, 0, _dummy.Length);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new ApplicationException("TCP CONNECTION DISCONNECTED");
                        }
                    }
                    _ssl.Flush();

                    _buffer = new byte[2048];
                    _tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 20000;

                    Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int bytesRead = _ssl.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        throw new EndOfStreamException("Error while reading");
                    }
                    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
                    _sb.Append(str);
                    if (SearchEndOfMessage(str)) break;
                }
                string text = _sb.ToString().Replace("\0", string.Empty);
                    //Console.WriteLine(text);

                    return _sb.ToString();
                    //sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  //  throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
                    return "WAS ERROR";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее решение.

```
var req = "$ STORE " + email.Uid + @" +flags (\\Deleted)" + "\r\n";
```

Comment: После установки \Deleted - нужно бы ещё сделать EXPUNGE.